# Can't use 2 monitors any more

Tags: windows, display, multiple-monitors, motherboard, gpu

Suddenly a couple of days ago my computer stopped using my second monitor (TV with HDMI).

After that I've tried with one other monitor and that with VGA and the TV with other HDMI cable as well.

But my computer does not even recognise either of those monitors.

I've tried everything I know so does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What OS? Have you tried to update / downgrade the GPU's drivers?

Comment: windows 10 and yes i have, updated bios aswell. Btw i have tried the hdmi on gpu and mobo but neither seem to work and the vga is obviously on mobo. im using dvi on my main monitor

Comment: Check `Settings` -> `System` -> `Display` -> `Multiple displays` - Is it set to `Extend` or `duplicate`?

Comment: pressing windows + p and there its set to only computer display but even if i switch it nothing happens and it automatically goes back to the same when i reopen it.

Comment: Did those monitors appear in your Device Manager?

Comment: no it only shows 1 monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that it worked fine a few days ago. The easiest way is running System Restore to a previous time point that everything worked fine.